# HTML5 Event Attributes: onmessage, onpopstate, onstorage

Tags: html, events, attributes

I am trying to learn the event attributes. However I couldn't find examples about the three attributes mentioned in the title. There are some examples done with JavaScript seems using the same events but as I don't know JavaScript I cannot understand them. What I ask is:

1) What actions trigger these attributes?

2) Could you please give me a piece of example code using these attributes?

I know the attributes fire a JavaScript function when triggered, therefore I need to know some JavaScript to be able to understand the examples. I can understand simple code pieces using the functions like alert(), document.write() etc. So your examples can include these.

Thanks in advance to everyone who try to help.

Comment: Onmessage: Here is an example http://help.dottoro.com/ljjqtjsj.php. And this is the trigger http://help.dottoro.com/ljgheukc.php.

Comment: onpostate: Triggers: history.pushState() and history.replaceState(). Example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onpopstate

Comment: onstorage: Don't know this one. Maybe this will help: http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-storage-event

Comment: Tahnks for sharing the links, however they don't use the attributes. They probably provided the same functionality with JavaScript but I am not familiar with JS. Therefore what I was looking for were examples with HTML event attributes like <body onmessage="script"...

Comment: You mean like <body onload="alert('page is now loading')">???

Comment: Yes, exactly like this but with onmessage, onpopstate and onstorage. The HTML5 specification shows these attributes are used with the body tag. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#attributes-1

The code can be like this: <body onload="exampleFunc">, and the function can include 'alert'.

Comment: Than what stops you from doing <body onmessage="alert('message posted')">. Or do you want an example for triggering this?

Comment: Yes, I did some tries but couldn't trigger. You are right, I am looking for ean example for triggering these.

Comment: Could you share me some tries? Maybe you did some wrong syntax.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <body onbeforeprint="print_att()" onmessage="message_att()">
    <p>Example text</p>
    <script>
        function print_att() {
            alert("Printing");
    }

    function message_att() {
        alert("Done");
    }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>`

Comment: I am sorry but it seems I cannot format the code as I intended, I cannot use the linebreak in the comments. I don't expect the code above to work because there is no indicator of which message will trigger the onmessage attribute. However I don't know how I can do this.

Comment: I can't find an example using the html attributes. Maybe you should learn more about js

Comment: I will, but for now I just wanted to see how it works. The example can include complex JS code (I can investigate the content) but I want to see the "onmessage" attribute is used. By the way, thanks for all your effort.